# Trying to compile a FC32 RPM on Centos6

Tags: linux, perl, build, rpm, specifications

I'm trying to build the fc32 perl-Test-Perl-Critic-Progressive on Centos6. I've yum installed Test::Perl::Critic anyhow. Aside from two deps that don't exist there, I do and get:

```
rpmbuild -ba perl-Test-Perl-Critic-Progressive.spec 
.
. lots of build stuff
.
RPM build errors:
    File must begin with "/": Artistic
    File must begin with "/": LICENSE
```

Googling suggests that something needs a full path.

*seconds later*

I commented out the %license statement in the %files section. Never mind, carry on.

Comment: Welcome to the Perl tag on Stack Overflow! Rather than editing the answer into your question, please write your own answer tomorrow and accept it, so others can benefit. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 2):

Rather than "getting rid" of `%license`, the better workaround is defining this macro, so that the license file is included to resulting RPM.
Here's what I do, assuming that the license filename is `LICENSE.md`:

```
%files
# Virtually add license macro for EL6:
%{!?_licensedir:%global license %%doc}
%license LICENSE.md
...
```

Comment: I'm not wildly concerned about LICENCE. Maybe I should be. I'm repackaging Open Source that isn't available on Centos 6,7 and 8 but is on Fedora.

Comment: @David.Hodgkinson: *Maybe I should be. I'm repackaging Open Source that isn't available on Centos 6,7 and 8 but is on Fedora* Did you look on EPEL? https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL